# Coding collision of two images

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create a program on codehs using JavaScript where I move around a character and collect rupees. Both my character and the four rupees are imported images. I tried to make it so that when the x and y of the character equals the x and y of the rupee, the rupee would disappear. However this hasn’t been working. I used to have a function where the rupees were in a list but this wasn’t working either. So instead I put everything under the global and start function to figure out what’s wrong. Simply the if statement to remove the rupees during collision aren’t working and I don’t know what to do. Here is my current code.

```
//x and y is the original coordinates
//that I can call upon in multiple
//functions and can change them whenever
//a key is pressed. Vixen is the image
//of the character that is put as a
//generalized variable so I can call
//upon it in several functions in order
//to change her location.
var x = 0;
var y = getHeight() - 70;
var vixen = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/4c30a0411738a2a2a5e638e657b6a8ca");
var rw1 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getWidth() - 40);
var rw2 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getWidth() - 40);
var rw3 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getWidth() - 40);
var rw4 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getWidth() - 40);
var rh1 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - 50);
var rh2 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - 50);
var rh3 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - 50);
var rh4 = Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - 50);
var rupee1 = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/6ff26ad5dba9ae888580ac1c3f8db64d");
var rupee2 = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/6ff26ad5dba9ae888580ac1c3f8db64d");
var rupee3 = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/6ff26ad5dba9ae888580ac1c3f8db64d");
var rupee4 = new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/6ff26ad5dba9ae888580ac1c3f8db64d");

function start(){
    vixen.setSize(48, 70);
    vixen.setPosition(x, y);
    add(vixen);
    
    keyDownMethod(move);
    
    rupee1.setSize(50, 60);
    rupee1.setPosition(rw1, rh1);
    println(rw1);
    println(rh1);
    add(rupee1);
    
    rupee2.setSize(50, 60);
    rupee2.setPosition(rw2, rh2);
    println(rw2);
    println(rh2);
    add(rupee2);
    
    rupee3.setSize(50, 60);
    rupee3.setPosition(rw3, rh3);
    println(rw3);
    println(rh3);
    add(rupee3);
    
    rupee4.setSize(50, 60);
    rupee4.setPosition(rw4, rh4);
    println(rw4);
    println(rh4);
    add(rupee4);
    
    if(x < rw1 + 40 && x + 48 > rw1 && y < rh1 + 50 && y + 70 > rh1){
        remove(rupee1);
    }
    if(x < rw2 + 40 && x + 48 > rw2 && y < rh2 + 50 && y + 70 > rh2){
        remove(rupee2);
    }
    if(x < rw3 + 40 && x + 48 > rw3 && y < rh3 + 50 && y + 70 > rh3){
        remove(rupee3);
    }
    if(x < rw4 + 40 && x + 48 > rw4 && y < rh4 + 50 && y + 70 > rh4){
        remove(rupee4);
    }
}

/*This function moves Vixen around 
the screen using the arrow key buttons*/
function move(e){
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        x -= 50;
        vixen.setPosition(x, y);
        
        println(x);
        println(y);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        x += 50;
        vixen.setPosition(x, y);
        
        println(x);
        println(y);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        y -= 50;
        vixen.setPosition(x, y);
        
        println(x);
        println(y);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        y += 50;
        vixen.setPosition(x, y);
        
        println(x);
        println(y);
    }
}
```

The print lines were to determine if the positions were correct and if my character’s position was being changed. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: You're using a `WebImage` class that looks like it might be something to do with .NET. I can't run this code because I don't have that class. Maybe this needs a .NET tag?

Comment: That isn’t a thing on codehs.